# Azure Service Bus/Service Fabric message not being removed from queue

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-service-fabric, azure-servicebus-queues

I am moving a calculation engine from an Azure worker role into Azure Service Fabric. It works by listening for messages on a Service Bus that it then processes based on the message content.

Currently, the calculation is working correctly but if the compute is taking longer than a minute or so the message does not get removed from the queue after completion. In the worker role, we solved this by increasing the "AutoRenewTimeout".

```
var options = new OnMessageOptions { AutoComplete = true, AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3) };
        _queueClient.OnMessage(OnMessage, options);
```

However, using the ["ServiceFabric.ServiceBus"](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.) nuget package, I cannot work out where you would set this. I have used the [demo project](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus/tree/master/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus.Demo) as a reference to set up a stateless service that actually runs the compute. Below is an extract from CalculateService.cs where the Stateless Service is initialised.

```
internal sealed class CalculateService : StatelessService
{
    public CalculateService(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., TCP, HTTP) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        string serviceBusQueueName = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("QueueName");
        yield return new ServiceInstanceListener(context => new ServiceBusQueueCommunicationListener(new Handler(this), context, serviceBusQueueName), "StatelessService-ServiceBusQueueListener");
    }
}


internal sealed class Handler : AutoCompleteServiceBusMessageReceiver
{
    protected override Task ReceiveMessageImplAsync(BrokeredMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(_service, $"Handling queue message {message.MessageId}");
        var computeRole = new ExcelCompute();
        var rMessage = new RangeMessage();
        rMessage = message.GetBody<RangeMessage>();
        var result = computeRole.OnMessage(rMessage, message.MessageId); //returns true if the compute was successful (which it currently, always is)
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
 }
```

I did try using the `<BrokeredMessage> message.Complete();` but that was throwing a message lock error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Get the latest version of the package (>= v3.5.0). Set the property '`MessageLockRenewTimeSpan`' on your `CommunicationListener` to a value that is smaller than your lock duration. (e.g. 50s where the lock duration is 60s) This allows for some clock skew. Note: by default this property is null, which means no automatic lock renewal is done.

*This option works well when processing a batch that takes more time than the lock duration allows.*

or

2. You can use [BrokeredMessage.RenewLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock.aspx) to periodically extend your message lock, when processing takes more time than the lock duration. You could do that inside a separate thread if needed.
   [May be useful info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433482/why-does-brokeredmessage-renewlock-only-renew-the-lock-for-a-few-seconds)

*This option works well when processing a single message (batch size 1) takes more time than the lock duration allows.*

Comment: Thanks LoekD, I'm subscribing to an end calculate event in a separate thread with that uses message.RenewLock until the event is fired. However, the AutoRenewTimeout support would be greatly appreciated!! :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've added the support, check out the demo for the details. Please let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: apologies for not coming back to you earlier. This did indeed resolve my issue perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and support. It is much appreciated! :)